# VSTS Hosted Agent (Hosted Linux Preview 2) - Environment variables are gone

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, powershell-core

In my build pipeline i have a powershell task which executes a script to gather information from the build.

It needs [agent and build variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts) which it would fetch from the environment variables.

The problem is: No environment variable is populated.

I get an empty result when i run this script:

```
Write-Host "Before"

Get-ChildItem env: | ft Name, Value -AutoSize | Out-String | Write-Host

Write-Host "After"
```

When i execute this using my private build agent (on windows) it runs fine.

Output on the buildserver:

```
==============================================================================
Task         : PowerShell
Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Windows, macOS, or Linux.
Version      : 2.136.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613736)
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Formatted command: . '/home/vsts/work/1/s/build/scripts/GatherDeploymentInfo.ps1'
[command]/usr/bin/pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command . '/home/vsts/work/_temp/1125300b-d6df-46f0-a852-041c22d2964f.ps1'
Before


After
```

SOLVED:

The fix ended up to be to change the buildagent from 'Hosted Linux Preview 2' to 'Hosted Ubuntu 1604'. That caused all environment to be visible again from within powershell core.

Comment: If you run in Linux why don't print the environment variables with Bash?

Comment: If you just want to print the environment variables you can easily do it with Bash.

Comment: You're right.

I've added an inline Command line task.
`#!/bin/bash`
`printenv`
Which indeed lists all environment variables.. So there seems to be a problem with Powershells Core's ability to get the environment variables from a linux box.
Edit: Or, more likely, with the configuration of powershell core on those hosted agents in VSTS.